# Duplicate of... appears in the initial flag dialog and after you press should be closed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flag-dialog

I am seeing the `duplicate of...` option twice in the flagging dialog. In the initial dialog and it appears once again after you press `should be closed..` Is this supposed to be like this and why?

[image]

Comment: Duplicates are both a close reason and a flag reason. Users who can not close vote, can flag a post as a duplicate. :) As such, it's in there twice.

Comment: @Catija The whole thing is just the flag dialog.  What the question describes is what people without the close vote privilege see when flagging.

Comment: @Servy But it's also what people who *can* close vote see. I'm guessing the "should be closed" section is pulled from the close vote dialogue directly... so it's in both places.

Comment: @Catija Yes, but the point is you can flag a post as a duplicate either from the top of the flag dialog or from within the flag for closure sub-dialog.  It still shows up twice.  The question isn't asking why you can access the close menu by either flagging for closure or clicking "close".  None of this has anything to do with the close vote privilege.

Comment: So... the "should be closed" dialogue has nothing to do with closing a post? Well, that's a surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We put it in two places to help people find it.

Duplicate is a bit of a weird option. Most of the other close reasons boil down to "this cannot or should not be answered" - duplicate is "this is *already* answered".

So folks don't necessarily look for it in the close options.